# Lists, Tuples, and Statistics Program Try-Except Block Error

Tags: python, list, error-handling, tuples, try-except

I am working on a Lists, Tuples, and Statistics Program for my intro class, and am having some difficulty with a try-except block. The program we are supposed to make is supposed to ask for the user to name a file to input, and then give some information about the numbers in that file. I have all of the information displays working correctly, but can't write the try-except block. The program needs to accept only the file name "new_numbers.txt" and nothing else.

Here is the top portion of my code:

```
    def main():
        #Get the name of the file from the user
        while(True):
                try:
                    input("Enter the name of the file you would like to open: ")
                except ValueError:
                    print("That file does not exist. Please enter a valid file.")
                    break
```

Comment: In your try statement, there is nothing for it to fail on.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been having problems with. This is the first program we have done where the input isn't a numeral, so I'm not sure how to set it up

Comment: Is there a traceback?

Comment: No, right now it's just looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **assign** the value from `input`, and try to `open` it to see if the file in question is around...:

```
def main():
    #Get the name of the file from the user
    while(True):
        try:
            fn = input('Enter the name of the file you would like to open: ')
            f = open(fn)
        except IOError:
            print('File {} does not exist. Please enter a valid file.'.format(fn))
        else:
            break
```

Also note that you should `break` only when there is **no more** error; and in that case the open file object is ready as variable `f`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This had me stumped for quite some time.

Comment: @jnfp7c, you're welcome!  Please remember (once enough time has elapsed since you asked) to **accept** the answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline to its left), a key bit of StackOverflow etiquette!-(